# Input Format in 2D array C++

Tags: c++, input, format, multidimensional-array

how to get input from user at student column then move cursor to cin at column Age of 2D array like that

```
student                   Age
 John                      12
 Sally                     20
 Edwar                     17
```

Comment: You can use an STL map if you don't want duplicates in the name,  otherwise use a vector that stores a stuct with the information.

Comment: i don't understand the question. you want this information from the user, and he should be entering it through the command line? or you wnat to know how to store this data? or something else?

Comment: @hoijui I want user to cin john at column student then cursor move to cin at column age

Comment: you should either ask for name first, and let the user write it and press enter, then then do the same for age, or make the use use a space or tab character or something as separator between name and age, though that would be very unintuitive. if you really need the user to enter data in a table format, it would be best to use some library for that; for example ncurses or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly get what you are trying to say but here is what I suggest

An array is homogeneous collection of data. You cannot enter data having 2 different datatypes in an array of a particular data type.
Ex: if you make an array of integer type then you can only enter integer type value in that array and not integer and character etc.
If you want to enter heterogeneous values, make a class containing 2 variables name array of type character and 
age of type integer. Each object of this class will have its own name and age variables. Create array of objects for different inputs.